Resource recommendations for Kolmogorov-Arnold-Moser Theory of discrete maps for a physics student
Looking for good books or resources that fully explain KAM theory of discrete systems for a physics student. Those that go deep into discrete maps that assume a pure math background and those that are meant for physics students always talk about the continuous time case with it's added complexity of differential equations etc. And even then often provide more of a description than any derivation. Even review papers that talk about key theorems and results (for e.g. Moser's twist map theorem) from a physics point of view are appreciated.
(P.S. I understand that since the topic is fairly abstract there's certainly going to be rigorous math involved which I don't mind,but physics literature and math literature often use a different language for describing these phenomena)

Please edit your question to explain what the acronym KAM means.
